# output of csc command to compile C# is not the same as compiling inside VS2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have VS2019, and i use its developer command prompt with the help of batch scripting to compile large number of c# source codes, now i noticed that even when the code is really simple, the output differ in like 3kb compared to when i compile with VS2019 (debug or release, default options) which outputs a 10KB file,  these are the options i tried with CSC to make them the same :

```
csc /debug- /optimize+ mycode.cs
csc /debug+ /optimize+ mycode.cs
csc /debug- /optimize- mycode.cs
csc /debug+ /optimize- mycode.cs
```

also tried setting `/debug:full`, still csc outputs a 7kb file, VS2019 outputs a 10KB file, why is this happening?

you can try it yourself, i created a c# form project, and just compiled it and it still was different from csc?

so when i open a c# form project and compile it in VS2019 (debug or release), shouldn't this be the same as just using csc mycode.cs?  (i think they should even produce the same hash, let alone a 3KB difference!)

Comment: You need to use the same compiler options as inside VS2019.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/command-line-building-with-csc-exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the build process from the commandline to compare the compiler options.

**Example command:**
(started in the project directory)

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims=: " %%i in (`vswhere -latest -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild`) do (
  if /i "%%i"=="installationPath" set InstallDir=%%j
)

::  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-command-line-reference?view=vs-2019
echo InstallDir=%InstallDir%
if exist "%InstallDir%\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" (
  "%InstallDir%\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" -nologo -verbosity:normal akFortune.sln -property:Configuration=Release
) else (
echo.
echo MSBuild not found!
echo expected in "%InstallDir%\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
echo.
goto xit
)
```

**Example output:**
(to give an impression of the complexity involved ....)

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:17
  01,1702 /fullpaths /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /highentropyva
  + /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
  " /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /refer
  ence:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
  " /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Data.dll" /re
  ference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Deployment.dll" /r
  eference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll" /reference:"
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:
  \Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /reference
  :"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\P
  rogram Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /link:C:\AK\cssrc
  \akFortune\akFortune2\obj\Release\Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Re
  lease\akFortune2.exe /subsystemversion:6.00 /resource:obj\Release\akFortune2.Form1.resources /resource:obj\Release\ak
  Fortune2.Properties.Resources.resources /resource:Resources\fortune.gz,akFortune2.Resources.fortune.gz /target:winexe
   /utf8output /win32icon:Fortune.ico /langversion:7.3 AutoStarter.cs Form1.cs Form1.Designer.cs Program.cs Properties\
  AssemblyInfo.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Settings.Designer.cs "obj\Release\.NETFramework,Version=v
  4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
```

Comment: How can i change the .NET framework version in csc and also tell it its a windows form project ?

Comment: Use *Visual Studio*, project properties, target framwork to select the desired *,NET Framework*. The same dialog has "Output type" to select between *Windows Application*, *Console Application* or *Class Library*. Then look at the build process as described.